# How to do a row number on UNION of 3 queries

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, union, row-number, amazon-athena

I am trying to write a query of row number function in Amazon Athena with 3 union queries, but my query fails stating `only one select statement allowed`. Any help would be appreciated as I am new to SQL.

```
(
 select id, name, address from table1
)
UNION
(
  select id, name, address from table2
)
UNION
(
  select * 
  from (
    select
      id,
      name,
      address,
      row_number() over (partition by id order by id)
    from table3
  ) as "t" 
  where "t".row_num = 1; 
)
```

Note: I am doing a row_num on 3rd table here because I want only unique values from 3rd table and distinct doesn't work directly on column using Athena.

Comment: Are you sure that is your actual query? There seems to be an error around `select * (select id, name`

Comment: yes its select * from (select... modified it

Comment: What are you wanting to achieve from the 3rd select? It is retrieving the first row for each `id`, but it is being sorted by `id`. Assuming that `id` is a primary key and is unique in every row, the `row_num = 1` is effectively doing nothing. Can you describe, in words, what the 3rd select is wanting to obtain?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is causing your problem, but there is a mismatch between the number of columns being returned by your SELECT statements:

- Table1: id, name, address
- Table2: id, name, address
- Table3: id, name, address, **row_number**

This would cause problems for UNION since there are a different number of columns.

Try changing `select *` into: `select id, name, address`